# Order results by number of other rows with the same column value?

Tags: python, sqlite, count, sql-order-by, window-functions

I have a table with the columns `id, GENUS, SPECIES`. The entries of the table many have multiple of the same `GENUS` but one unique `SPECIES` per.

```
id, GENUS, SPECIES
0 ,  Homo, Sapiens
1 ,  Homo, Habilis
2 , Canis, Familiaris 
3 , Canis, Lupus
4 , Canis, Rufus
```

I would like to generate a query where the results are ordered by the rows of the most numerous `GENUS` first.

```
id, GENUS, SPECIES
2 , Canis, Familiaris 
3 , Canis, Lupus
4 , Canis, Rufus
0 ,  Homo, Sapiens
1 ,  Homo, Habilis
```

It seems that I could need to first calculate the unique values of the column, count the number of each, make a new column with that value for each row, then sort by that row, and select the original columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `COUNT()` window function in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
ORDER BY COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY GENUS) DESC, 
         GENUS, -- in case more than 1 GENUS have the same rows keep the rows of the GENUS together
         id;    -- sort the rows of each GENUS by id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=d6d958090c291c28e2326d9cfbce1334).